# Binomial theorem-respecting polynomials

Tags: polynomials, binomial-theorem

I'll call a family of polynomials "binomial theorem-respecting" if they satisfy:

$$
f_m(x+k) = \sum_{i=0}^m {m \choose i} k^{m-i} f_i(x)
$$

For example, the family of polynomials $f_m(x) = x^m$ satisfies the above. Slightly more generally, the family of polynomials $f_m(x, c) = (x+c)^m$ also satisfies the above.

I've found a more complicated family that looks like:

$$
\begin{align}
f_0(x, c) &= 1\\
f_1(x, c) &= x\\
f_2(x, c) &= x^{2} - c\\
f_3(x, c) &= x^{3} - 3 x c\\
f_4(x, c) &= x^{4} - 6 x^{2} c + 3 c^{2} + 2 c\\
f_5(x, c) &= x^{5} - 10 x^{3} c + 15 x c^{2} + 10 x c\\
f_6(x, c) &= x^{6} - 15 x^{4} c + 45 x^{2} c^{2} + 30 x^{2} c - 15 c^{3} - 30 c^{2} - 16 c\\
...
\end{align}
$$

For $c=0$, this is the original family $f_m(x) = x^m$.

Are there more families? Is there a general construction of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Polynomials $f_m$ which fulfil
\begin{align*}
f_m(x+y)=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}f_k(x)f_{m-k}(y)
\end{align*}
are said to be of *[binomial type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_type)*.

**[2022-11-14]**: Thanks to the comment of @Cam.Davidson.Pilon I'd also like to point to *[Appell sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_sequence)*. These are polynomials of the form
\begin{align*}
f_m(x+y)=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}f_k(y)x^{m-k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
This identity (1) is called *Appell Identity*. It is stated as Theorem 2.5.8 in *[Umbral Calculus](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/the-umbral-calculus)* by Steven Roman where this and related topics are thoroughly treated.

Comment: Well that solves that! Thanks for the tip @epi163sqrt

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon: You're welcome. :-)

Comment: For future visitors, the specific term is an Appell sequence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_sequence

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon: Many thanks for your hint. I've added information accordingly.